# "TypeError: person.removeRole is not a function"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to create a timed mute bot for my discord server, but then it says "Person.removeRole is not a function"
Is there any fix for this?

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'mute':
      var person = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]));
      if (!person) return message.reply("I can't find the user noob ");

      let mainrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Epic Members");
      let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "mute");


      if (!role) return message.reply(" can't find the mute role noob, Create a mute role named 'mute'.")


      let time = args[2];
      if (!time) {
        return message.reply("Put a dman time u noob");
      }

      person.removeRole(mainrole.id)
      person.addRole(role.id);


      message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has now been muted for ${ms(ms(time))}`)

      setTimeout(function() {

        person.addRole(mainrole.id)
        person.removeRole(role.id);
        console.log(role.id)
        message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has been unmuted noob`)
      }, ms(time));
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.addRole()` and `.removeRole()` methods only exist in the `GuildMember` class in v11 ([docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember)): if you're using discord.js@v12 you'll need to use the [`GuildMember.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMemberRoleManager) property:

```js
person.roles.remove(mainrole)
person.roles.add(role)
```

Comment: @John Happy to hear that :) To "close" this question you can accept this answer by clicking the tick on the left: this way the question will be marked as resolved for everyone

Answer (score 2):

Check you work with discord.js V12 and use:

```
person.roles.remove(roleResolvable)
person.roles.add(roleResolvable)
```

Also check: [Discord.js: Role Manager -> add](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add)

(A role resolvable can be a role object or an id)